# Android Retrieve Values from SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Android and SQLite databases. I am working through a tutorial, but I am having trouble adapting it to my app.

I want to build a High Score database with a high score for each level. So, my table would be called HighScore and the fields id, Level, and HighScore. Level and HighScore are Integers.

Here are my classes:

```html
public class HighScore {

    private int id;
    private Integer Level;
    private Integer highscore;

    public HighScore(){}

    public HighScore(Integer Level, Integer highscore) {
        super();
        this.Level = Level;
        this.highscore = highscore;
    }

    //getters & setters

    
    public Integer getHighScore() {
        return highscore;
    }

    public Integer getLevel() {
        return Level;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLevel(Integer Level) {
        this.Level = Level;
    }

    public void setHighScore(Integer highscore) {
        this.highscore = highscore;
    }
}
```

```html
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HighScore";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create HighScores table
        String CREATE_HighScore_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE HighScores ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "Level INTEGER, "+
                "HIGHSCORE INTEGER )";

        // create HighScores table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_HighScore_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older HighScores table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HighScores");

        // create fresh books table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * CRUD operations (create "add", read "get", update, delete) book + get all books + delete all books
     */

    // HighScores table name
    private static final String TABLE_HIGHSCORES = "HighScores";

    // HighScores Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_LEVEL = "Level";
    private static final String KEY_HIGHSCORE = "HIGHSCORE";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_LEVEL,KEY_HIGHSCORE};

    public void addHighScore(HighScore highScore){
        Log.d("addHighScore", highScore.toString());
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_LEVEL, highScore.getLevel()); // get title
        values.put(KEY_HIGHSCORE, highScore.getHighScore()); // get author

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_HIGHSCORES, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }

    public HighScore getHighScore(Integer Level){

        // 1. get reference to readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // 2. build query
        Cursor cursor =
                db.query(TABLE_HIGHSCORES, // a. table
                        COLUMNS, // b. column names
                        " Level = ?", // c. selections
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(Level) }, // d. selections args
                        null, // e. group by
                        null, // f. having
                        null, // g. order by
                        null); // h. limit

        // 3. if we got results get the first one
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        // 4. build highScore object
        HighScore highScore = new HighScore();
        //highScore.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        //highScore.setLevel(cursor.getInt(1));
        highScore.setHighScore(cursor.getInt(2));

        Log.d("getHighScore("+Level+")", highScore.toString());

        // 5. return highScore
        return highScore;
    }

    // Get All HighScores
    public List<HighScore> getAllHighScores() {
        List<HighScore> highScores = new LinkedList<HighScore>();

        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HIGHSCORES;

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // 3. go over each row, build highScore and add it to list
        HighScore highScore = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                highScore = new HighScore();
                highScore.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                highScore.setLevel(cursor.getInt(1));
                highScore.setHighScore(cursor.getInt(2));

                // Add highScore to highScores
                highScores.add(highScore);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.d("getAllHighScores()", highScores.toString());

        // return highScores
        return highScores;
    }

    // Updating single highScore
    public int updateHighScore(HighScore highScore) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Level", highScore.getLevel()); // get title
        values.put("HighScore", highScore.getHighScore()); // get author

        // 3. updating row
        int i = db.update(TABLE_HIGHSCORES, //table
                values, // column/value
                KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(highScore.getId()) }); //selection args

        // 4. close
        db.close();

        return i;

    }

    // Deleting single highScore
    public void deleteHighScore(HighScore highScore) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete
        db.delete(TABLE_HIGHSCORES,
                KEY_ID+" = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(highScore.getId()) });

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        Log.d("deleteHighScore", highScore.toString());

    }
}
```

And then in my SetStartupValues of my main class, I have this code:

```html
        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        intHighScore = db.getHighScore(intLevel);
```

What I would like to do is when the SetStartUpValues method runs, I can get the high score from the table for the users intLevel. But intHighScore is an integer and the getHighScore method returns a HighScore object. How can I get 1 field value from the HighScore object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change your getHighScore as the following

```
public int getHighScore(Integer Level){

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE_HIGHSCORES, // a. table
                    COLUMNS, // b. column names
                    " Level = ?", // c. selections
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(Level) }, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. return highScore
    return cursor.getInt(2);

}
```

Instead of creating a `HighScore` object, just return the `Integer` value of the `HighScore`.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. That works! Unfortunately though, I have to wait 7 minutes to mark this post as the answer. Thanks again.